# Applying CV2 Grayscale to a Numpy 4D array

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

While I know how to convert a single color image (32,32,3) to grayscale using `CV2`:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor( img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY )
```

I need to convert a batch of 60,000 images in a 4D numpy array (60000,32,32,3), how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your 4D array of images is called `img_stack` with shape (60000,32,32,3).

You could do:

```
gray_stack = np.empty_like(img_stack[...,0])
for i in range(img_stack.shape[0]):
    gray_stack[i] = cv2.cvtColor(img_stack[i], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Resulting shape is (60000,32,32).

Or you could do:

```
gray_stack = np.empty_like(img_stack[...,:1])
for i in range(img_stack.shape[0]):
    gray_stack[i,:,:,0] = cv2.cvtColor(img_stack[i], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Resulting shape is (60000,32,32,1).

---

Bonus Tensorflow solution:

```
gray_stack = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(img_stack, name=None)
```

Resulting shape will be (60000,32,32,1).

The above OpenCV solutions might actually perform faster.

Answer (score 1):

One more option using `numpy`:

```
grayscale_imgs = np.dot(img_stack, [0.299 , 0.587, 0.114])
grayscale_imgs.shape # => (60000, 32, 32)
```

More about the weighted sum can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Luma_coding_in_video_systems)